# $filter working but resulting in "Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

So I have a JSON object that looks a little something like this:

```
{
    "conversations":[
        {
            "_id": "55f1595d72b67ea90d008",
            "topic_id": 30,
            "topic": "First Conversation",
            "admin": "admin@gmail.com",
            "__v": 0,
            "messages": [
                {
                    "body": "Hello?",
                    "timestamp": "2015-09-10T10:20:40.000Z",
                    "from": "admin@gmail.com",
                    "_id": "55f1597a72b67ea90d009"
                }
            ],
            "to": [
                "me@gmail.com"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm trying to create a custom filter to look for messages within the different conversations. I need the filter to return the conversation, the message, the sender, and the timestamp of the message that matches the filter.

My custom filter looks like this:

```
.filter('searchForMessage', function() {
    return function(arr, searchString) {
        if (!searchString) {
            return arr;
        }
        var result = [];
        searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
        angular.forEach(arr, function(conversation) {
            for (var i = 0; i < conversation.messages.length; i++) {
                if (conversation.messages[i].body.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
                    result.push({
                        conversation: conversation,
                        message: conversation.messages[i].body,
                        from: conversation.messages[i].from,
                        timestamp: conversation.messages[i].timestamp
                    });
                }
            }       
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```

This filter works, as in it's returning all the right data, but I also get "Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!".

Anyone know why this is occurring?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your filter is returning each time new values (when you push the elements). Angular will see that it's not strictly the same value (=== comparison), and will trigger a new digest.

To fix this, you need to constantly return an array with the exact same elements.

Comment: I don't get what you mean when you say it needs to constantly return an array with the exact same elements? Surely then if I update the search term the result for the filter won't update?

Comment: What I mean is that your filter function has to be a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function): for a given set of inputs (your data array and your search query), you have to always return the exact same output. Of course, you can still return different outputs for different inputs (for example for a different search query).

Comment: But surely a normal filter returns new values each time? Sorry for seeming stubborn, but I'm just struggling to get my head around this.

Comment: They return a different array, but the same set of objects. For example, a valid filter (ES6 syntax) would be `set => { return set.filter(object => object.id % 2 === 0) }` and an invalid one would be `set => { return set.map(object => object.id); }` (because in the second case, you create new different objects at each invocation, triggering a new digest loop ad vitam aeternam). In short: only use filters to filter data, not to create or modify existing ones.